# Init array of integer in delphi

Tags: delphi

how to init an array like

```
TMyArray = array[1..2, 1..3] of Integer;
```

I tried

```
 MyArray  :  TMyArray;

 MyArray = ( (1,2,3),  (3,4,5) );
```

But did not have any luck with this style ...

Comment: Which version of Delphi?

Comment: What difference does it make, @Bruce? Are there lots of different answers, based on the version? And are those answers so long and involved that a single answer couldn't be written as a simple *case* statement: "For version A and older, do X; if you have version B through C, then do Y; for version D and later, then do Z"?

Comment: @Rob: Newer versions have more options.  For example, David's suggestion below only works in Delphi 2009 (?) and above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can initialise a typed constant as part of its declaration:

```
const
  MyArrayConst: TMyArray = (
     (1, 2, 3),
     (3, 4, 5)
  );
```

Or you can initialise a global variable in this way.

But you cannot initialise a local variable in that fashion. You could declare the constant, and then assign it to your variable.

```
var
  MyArray: TMyArray;
....
MyArray := MyArrayConst;
```

Comment: we are using static arrays, this solution works perfect , thanks

Answer (score 5):

In case you can use dynamic arrays you could use code like

```
type
  TDynIntArray = array of Integer;
  T2DIntArray  = array of TDynIntArray;

var tmp: T2DIntArray;
begin
  tmp := T2DIntArray.Create(
                 TDynIntArray.Create(1,2,3),
                 TDynIntArray.Create(4,5,6)
          );
```

Comment: If you used `TArray<TArray<Integer>>` then you would not need to define types, and you would not force anyone else that wanted to interact with your code to use the same types. One of the by products of generics is that it has more relaxed type compatibility rules which get around the overly fussy old style pascal rules.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan "overly fussy old style pascal rules" - I now have a new favorite phrase. :-)

Comment: @alcalde TArray<T> seems like such a small thing but it's one of the most important new features in the language.